# 64 Bit Windows Server Clones are not pinging to each other

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-workstation

I have 2 clones of 64 bit windows server hosted upon windows 7 64 bit using VMWare Workstation 7.0, i am struggling to ping virtual machines but it is not pinging. i have checked all network settings, firewall is off. if i use 32 bit virtual machine then i don't have any problem only this issue is with 64 bit clones... please suggest. thanks in advance.

Comment: So if its not pinging, what is it doing instead? It should give you an error message.

Comment: Is the windows firewall turned on?

Answer (score 3):

Do they have different MAC addresses?  If not then they will be unable to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using bridge, NAT or host-only network? Make sure the machines are on the same network segment and are using the same network adapter.